# LazyList is not defined in ZUL Page

Tags: java, widget, sap-commerce-cloud, zk, backoffice

I'm trying to pass data from DAO with flexbile search query trough to the zul page using de the widgetModel. But when I print the widgetModel.orders it says...

> (index):93 Uncaught ReferenceError: LazyList is not defined
> at window.onload ((index):93)

zul page

```js
                window.onload = function () {
                    const myChart = new Chart(
                            document.getElementById('myChart'),
                            config
                    );

                    const test = [[${widgetModel.orders}]];
                    console.log(test);

                };
```

controller class

```java
public class customGraphController extends DefaultWidgetController {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7954736389190109887L;

    @WireVariable
    private transient customGraphService customGraphService;


    @Override
    public void preInitialize(Component comp) {
        super.preInitialize(comp);

        WidgetModel model = getWidgetInstanceManager().getModel();
        model.put("orders", customGraphService.getAllOrders());

    }
}
```

service class

```java
public class customGraphService {

    @Autowired
    private OrdersDataDao ordersDataDao;

    public List<OrderModel> getAllOrders() {
        return ordersDataDao.getAllOrders();
    }

}
```

dao class

```java
public class OrdersDataDao {


    @Resource
    private FlexibleSearchService flexibleSearchService;

    public List<OrderModel> getAllOrders() {
        final String stringQuery = "select {o.pk} from {order as o}";
        final FlexibleSearchQuery query = new FlexibleSearchQuery(stringQuery);
        final SearchResult<OrderModel> result = flexibleSearchService.search(query);
        if (null != result.getResult()) {
            return result.getResult();
        } else {
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Does someone knows a solution?

Comment: Hi  It's wrong way to send data to zul file . you should have definition.xml there you can bin few source then you should have corresponding controller to populate the values in zul.

Answer (score 0):

window.onLoad is always too early to manipulate ZK widgets. The onLoad callback will trigger once the initial document has been loaded, but that document itself will load ZK libaries, initialize the client engine, etc.

If you need to do something "after libraries have been loaded", you can use [zk.afterload](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Client-side_Reference/Introduction/Object_Oriented_Programming_in_JavaScript#Do_After_Load). This hook is good if you need to modify a framework function before the widgets actually use it.

However, this is still before widget instantiation by the client engine, so if your goal is to access a widget, it is still too early.

If you want to do something to a widget after that widget has been added to the page an initialized, what you actually need is a [client-side onBind listener](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Client-side_Reference/Notifications/Widget_Events).

You can set that listener in zul or in java, but the simplest way to do that is like this: https://zkfiddle.org/sample/1v9phuk/1-Another-new-ZK-fiddle

Lastly, if you are going to use ZK's client-side API to access / modify content at client-side, I'd recommend looking into the [ZK client-side selectors](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Client-side_Reference/General_Control/Client-side_selection_of_elements_and_widgets). Way easier than trying to manually lookup elements by ID, and way more robust in the long run.
`document.getElementById('myChart')` will only work if you have a dom element with the actual ID "myChart", which is not how ZK works (not with default UUID generator anyway).
Instead, you can select a widget by it's ZK ID.
Assuming you have `<charts id="myChart" />` in your zul, you can get the ZK widget directly as argument to the onBind listener, or you can get it with the ZK selector:
`zk.$("$myChart")`, and from there you can get the DOM node: `zk.$("$myChart").$n()`

Make sure you know what is client-side (JavaScript), and what is Server side.

(Lastly)^2, keep in mind that in a ZK architecture, the server is the source of the state, and the client only update the state by sending client commands back to the server.
If you use JS to modify the client-side state, you can create desynchronization between the server-side state and the client-side state, so proceed with caution.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, I used GSON to stringify the list and than pass it to the zul page :-)

```java
    private Object convertAllOrderModelsToJSON() {
        //get all the models
        List list = customGraphService.getAllOrdersModels();
        //convert models to JSON
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        String json = gson.toJson(list);
        return json;

    }
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer by adding your code ?